# ical4j keeps losing the Z at the end of exdate

Tags: icalendar, ical4j

Ical4j Exdate property rejects the Z at the end of an utc EXDATE that has been parsed from an ical file. How to I make it retain the Z. I have tried removing the EXDATE and setting a new EXDATE with the desired format but it still does not work and the Z still gets rejected. Please find below the code I have written:

```
Iterator<Property> iterator = cal.getComponents().get(0).getProperties().iterator(); 
//This iterator iterates over the properties of the one component in a parsed out calendar "cal"

DateList list = new DateList(net.fortuna.ical4j.model.parameter.Value.DATE_TIME);
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      Property p = iterator.next();
      if (p.getName().equals("EXDATE")) {

                StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder(p.getValue());
                value.append("Z");
                System.out.println("New ExDate :" + value.toString());
                Date date = new Date(value.toString(), "yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss'Z'");
                list.add(date);
                iterator.remove();
      }
}
if (!list.isEmpty()) {
      cal.getComponents().get(0).getProperties().add(new ExDate(list));
}
for (final Property p : cal.getComponents().get(0).getProperties()) {
            System.out.println(p.getName() + ":" + p.getValue());
}
```

The result obtained are in the format 
EXDATE:20151117T190000,20151118T190000

How do I make it retain the Z at the end of the time stamps like "20151117T190000Z" as it is causing my client to not understand the exdate and ignore it completely. These values are stored in a caldav server before the client pulls it from there

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do setUtc(true) on your DateList ?

Comment: Yes I did it still keeps losing the Z